# PouchDB's find() always says "no matching index" even if I make one

Tags: pouchdb

Given a new database :

```
db = PouchDB('testing @ '+new Date().getTime() );
```

And a new index

```
await db.createIndex({
    index: {fields: ['type']}
});
```

Finding all documents by that index :

```
await db.find({
    selector: {
        type:'hip',
    },
    sort: [{'_id':'desc'}], 
})
```

always includes a warning in the result that "no matching index found".

Comment: Solution is to include sort param in the selector, even as a null no-op, 
await db.find({ selector: { type:'hip',_id:{"$gte":null }}, sort: [{'_id':'desc'}], });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query depends on two fields: `type` and `_id`.  But your index only provides one: `type`.

To do sorting with a Mango query, your sort columns must be indexed, too.

Your selector also needs to reference the ordering columns. This can be done, without affecting the result set, by adding something like:

```
_id: {"$gte": null}
```

Comment: Doesn't work : 
await db.createIndex({
    index: {fields: ['type','_id']}
});
await db.find({
    selector: {
        type:'hip',
    },
    sort: [{'_id':'desc'}], 
});
// still says "no matching index"

Comment: Column order matters,too. Did you try `['_id','type']` as well?

Comment: You might also need to include `_id` in the selector. `_id: {"$gte": null}` would be one way to do that without affecting the result set.

Comment: Changing index order has no effect. Adding to selector does

Comment: Great, glad to hear you found a solution. I've added that to the answer, too.